# How to build a cross-compiler for i386-apple-darwin target from x86_64-apple-darwin host?

Tags: macos, gcc, cross-compiling, gnu, darwin

**Problem overview**

I am trying to learn how to build a cross-compiler, specifically a version of GNU `gcc` 4.7.2 on a 64-bit Intel OS X host that targets `i386-apple-darwin` (32-bit Intel). However, I keep getting stuck on the same error:

```
...
checking for i386-apple-darwin-gcc... /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/lib/ -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/include -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/sys-include
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Build process**

I first build a version of GNU `binutils` which targets `i386-apple-darwin`, which is accessible to the GNU `gcc` build folder:

```
$ cd third-party
$ wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.23.2.tar.bz2
$ tar xjvf binutils-2.23.2.tar.bz2
$ mkdir i386-apple-darwin
$ mkdir build-binutils && cd build-binutils
$ ../binutils-2.23.2/configure --target=i386-apple-darwin --prefix="/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc"
$ make all && make install
...
```

Then I try to build a targeted version of `gcc` as follows:

```
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party
$ wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
$ tar xvjf gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
$ cd gcc-4.7.2
$ ./contrib/download_prerequisites
... /* this grabs GMP, MPC and MPFR dependencies */
$ cd ..
$ mkdir build-gcc && cd build-gcc
$ ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --target=i386-apple-darwin --prefix="/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/Bedops/bedops/third-party/i386-apple-gcc"
$ make
...
```

After about 30 minutes of compiling stuff, it gets stuck with the error message shown above.

**Error details**

To track down the source of the error, here is a snippet of `build-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/libgcc/config.log`:

```
configure:3344: /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/lib/ -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/include -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3355: $? = 1
configure:3344: /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/lib/ -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/include -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3355: $? = 1
configure:3371: /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/lib/ -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/include -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid listing option `r'
configure:3374: $? = 1
configure:3562: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3584: /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/ -B/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/lib/ -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/include -isystem /Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid listing option `r'
configure:3588: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3602: error: in `/Users/alexpreynolds/Developer/third-party/build-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/libgcc':
configure:3605: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

**The compiler I'm bootstrapping from**

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc47 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc47 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.7 --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.7 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --disable-ppl-version-check --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal)
```

**Question**

Is there a step I missed in setting up the build environment of `coreutils` or `gcc` such that this error results?

What else can I troubleshoot in trying to resolve this error? My Google searches on this error message are not bearing much fruit.

---

**Changes**

I changed the build script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

WORK_DIR=$PWD
INSTALL_DIR=$WORK_DIR/gcc-4.7.2-darwin
MIN_OSX_VERSION=10.5

if [ -d "$INSTALL_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Directory $INSTALL_DIR already exists";
    exit 1
fi

BINUTILS=binutils-2.23.2
TARBALL_BINUTILS=$BINUTILS.tar.bz2
URL_BINUTILS=http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/$TARBALL_BINUTILS
SOURCE_BINUTILS_DIR=$WORK_DIR/$BINUTILS
BUILD_BINUTILS_DIR=$WORK_DIR/build-$BINUTILS

GCC=gcc-4.7.2
TARBALL_GCC=$GCC.tar.bz2
URL_GCC=http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc/$GCC/$TARBALL_GCC
SOURCE_GCC_DIR=$WORK_DIR/$GCC
BUILD_GCC_DIR=$WORK_DIR/build-$GCC

curl -O $URL_BINUTILS
mkdir -p $SOURCE_BINUTILS_DIR
tar -xjvf $TARBALL_BINUTILS
rm $TARBALL_BINUTILS
mkdir -p $BUILD_BINUTILS_DIR
cd $BUILD_BINUTILS_DIR
$SOURCE_BINUTILS_DIR/configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR
make -j $(sysctl -n hw.availcpu) all CFLAGS='-Wno-error' && make install

find $INSTALL_DIR -name '*strip*' -delete

cd $WORK_DIR

curl -O $URL_GCC
mkdir -p $SOURCE_GCC_DIR
tar -xvjf $TARBALL_GCC
rm $TARBALL_GCC
cd $SOURCE_GCC_DIR
sed -i '' -e 's/wget/curl -O/g' $SOURCE_GCC_DIR/contrib/download_prerequisites
$SOURCE_GCC_DIR/contrib/download_prerequisites
cd $WORK_DIR
mkdir -p $BUILD_GCC_DIR
cd $BUILD_GCC_DIR
$SOURCE_GCC_DIR/configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j $(sysctl -n hw.availcpu) CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=$MIN_OSX_VERSION" && make install

find $INSTALL_DIR -name '*.a' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ranlib

rm -Rf $BUILD_GCC_DIR
rm -Rf $BUILD_BINUTILS_DIR
rm -Rf $SOURCE_GCC_DIR
rm -Rf $SOURCE_BINUTILS_DIR
```

The `ranlib` step was necessary due to numerous errors during the process of building a library.

To build an `i386` binary, I had to do the following with my `Makefile`:

```
ARCH                 = i386
...
GCCDIR               = ${PARTY3}/gcc-4.7.2-darwin
GCCBINDIR            = ${GCCDIR}/bin
GCCLIBDIR            = ${GCCDIR}/lib
GCCINCDIR            = ${GCCDIR}/include
...
LIBCPP               = libgcc_eh.a
LIBCXX               = libstdc++.a
...
INCLUDES             = -I${GCCINCDIR} ...
...
CC                   = ${GCCBINDIR}/gcc
CXX                  = ${GCCBINDIR}/g++
...
GCCCPPLIBPATH        = ${GCCLIBDIR}/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0/4.7.2/${ARCH}/${LIBCPP}
GCCCXXLIBPATH        = ${GCCLIBDIR}/${ARCH}/${LIBCXX}
...
FLAGS                = ${SFLAGS} ${NONSTATICFLAGS} ${OBJS} -L${GCCLIBDIR} ...
...
run: dependencies
    mkdir -p ${BIN} && ${CXX} -o ${BIN}/${PROG}_${ARCH} ${FLAGS} -static-libgcc -mmacosx-version-min=${MIN_OSX_VERSION} -arch ${ARCH} ... ${GCCCPPLIBPATH} ${GCCCXXLIBPATH} ${SOURCE1}
```

Summary of `Makefile` changes:

1. I had to add the `-static-libgcc` flag and leave out `-static-libstdc++`, which had no effect (except to cause the build to fail, until I ran `ranlib` on the static libraries, which fixed the build failure but had no effect on `-static-libstdc++`).
2. I added `${GCCCPPLIBPATH}` and `${GCCCXXLIBPATH}` to the `run` target, which each point to the static C anc C++ libraries `libgcc_eh.a` and `libstdc++.a`, respectively.

This allowed me to compile a working `i386` (32-bit) binary, but the same GCC installation failed to build a working `x86_64` (64-bit) binary.

Comment: I haven't built that target of compiler, but those options `xgcc` is failing with look like they're for e.g. IBM's `xlc`, I.e. is the configure script is confused about what compiler it is using?  I would start investigation by tracing back what configure line generated the error, and trying to understand how that configure line was generated.

Answer (score 4):

After thinking about this a little, it occurs to me that by far the easiest solution would be to compile GCC for x86_64, and then to just pass `-m32` when you wish to build for i386. Is that not sufficient for your needs for some reason? Building in this manner is dramatically simpler, and doesn't require any of the madness described below. Doing the following sequence of events results in a working compiler that will spit out i386 binaries when requested:

```
WORK_DIR=$PWD
INSTALL_DIR=$WORK_DIR/install

curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.23.2.tar.bz2
tar xjvf binutils-2.23.2.tar.bz2
mkdir build-binutils && cd build-binutils
../binutils-2.23.2/configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR
make -j $(sysctl -n hw.availcpu) all CFLAGS='-Wno-error' && make install

find $INSTALL_DIR -name '*strip*' -delete

cd $WORK_DIR

curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
tar xvjf gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
cd gcc-4.7.2
sed -i '' -e 's/wget/curl -O/g' ./contrib/download_prerequisites
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir build-gcc && cd build-gcc
../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j $(sysctl -n hw.availcpu) && make install
```

Once this completes you can see it in action like so:

```
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ cat > test.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cerr << "Built with GCC 4.7" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

^D
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ ./install/bin/g++ -o test test.cpp 
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ file test
test: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ ./install/bin/g++ -m32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o test test.cpp 
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ file test
test: Mach-O executable i386
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ otool -L ./test
./test:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1192.0.0)
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$ ./test 
Built with GCC 4.7
mrowe@falcon:~/tmp$
```

If you see warnings like:

```
ignoring file …/4.7.2/i386/libgcc.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

You can fix them by running `ranlib` on the static libraries:

```
find $INSTALL_DIR -name '*.a' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ranlib
```

---

Below is my attempt at helping you along the path you were attempting to follow. I don't think it's the ideal approach and it is fraught with problems.

The error you reported seeing is due to your GCC build trying to use the GNU assembler from binutils when the generated assembly is intended to be assembled with the GNU assembler from Apple's cctools. The dialect of assembly that is supported differs between the two as Apple's assembler diverged from the upstream GNU assembler many years ago.

All of the instructions I was able to find for building cctools were out of date so I experimented until I got something working. I did something close to the following:

```
curl -O http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/cctools/cctools-829.tar.gz
tar xvzf cctools-829.tar.gz
cd cctools-829
```

You'll then need to patch two files in order to build without a dependency on LLVM:

```
diff -ru cctools-829/libstuff/lto.c cctools-829.modified/libstuff/lto.c
--- cctools-829/libstuff/lto.c  1969-12-31 16:00:00.000000000 -0800
+++ cctools-829.modified/libstuff/lto.c 2013-04-05 03:18:34.000000000 -0700
@@ -376,4 +376,18 @@
        lto_dispose(mod);
 }

+#else 
+
+#include <stdlib.h>
+
+__private_extern__
+int
+is_llvm_bitcode(
+                struct ofile *ofile,
+                char *addr,
+                size_t size)
+{
+    return 0;
+}
+
 #endif /* LTO_SUPPORT */
diff -ru cctools-829/misc/libtool.c cctools-829.modified/misc/libtool.c
--- cctools-829/misc/libtool.c  1969-12-31 16:00:00.000000000 -0800
+++ cctools-829.modified/misc/libtool.c 2013-04-05 03:20:21.000000000 -0700
@@ -1369,8 +1369,11 @@
                    }
                }
                 }
-                else if(ofiles[i].arch_type == OFILE_Mach_O ||
-                        ofiles[i].arch_type == OFILE_LLVM_BITCODE){
+                else if(ofiles[i].arch_type == OFILE_Mach_O
+#ifdef LTO_SUPPORT
+                            || ofiles[i].arch_type == OFILE_LLVM_BITCODE
+#endif
+                            ){
                if(cmd_flags.ranlib == TRUE){
                    error("for architecture: %s file: %s is not an "
                          "archive (no processing done on this file)",
```

And then build:

```
make install USE_DEPENDENCY_FILE=NO BUILD_DYLIBS=NO LTO= TRIE= DSTROOT=../build-cctools
```

And install the necessary parts of by hand:

```
cd ..
cp build-cctools/usr/bin/as i386-apple-gcc/bin/i386-apple-darwin-as
cp build-cctools/usr/bin/as i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/as
cp build-cctools/usr/bin/lipo i386-apple-gcc/bin/i386-apple-darwin-lipo
cp build-cctools/usr/bin/lipo i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/lipo
cp build-cctools/usr/bin/strip i386-apple-gcc/bin/i386-apple-darwin-strip
cp build-cctools/usr/bin/strip i386-apple-gcc/i386-apple-darwin/bin/strip
```

If we then attempt to build GCC once more we'll discover that the build process is upset because our freshly-built assembler is unable to target x86_64. Since that doesn't seem relevant to what you're trying to achieve you can add the `--disable-multilib` argument to GCC's configure script to prevent it from trying that.

At this point I ran in to errors while attempting to build libgcc. These errors are because a suitable linker cannot be found, so I guess that now you'd need to [download](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/ld64/ld64-134.9.tar.gz) and build ld64 too.

And it's at this point that I've run out of time to make it any further. Good luck!

Comment: Passing -m32 isn't sufficient because I am trying to build static, 32-bit versions of GNU's C and C++ libraries, which I can link into 32-bit binaries. The -m32 option does not do that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but after building I end up with $PREFIX/lib/i386/libstdc++.a which would appear to be the 32-bit version of the GNU C++ library. All of the other GCC support libraries are also built for 32-bit as well as 64-bit.

Comment: I'll give your method a shot to see if I can replicate it on my end. Thanks for adding all this detail.

Comment: Is your patchfile incomplete? I get the following error when I attempt to apply it: `patching file misc/libtool.c - patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line - Hunk #1 FAILED at 1369. - 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file misc/libtool.c.rej`

Comment: I also tried a second, separate attempt, where I used `llvm-gcc42` and added `CFLAGS='-m32'` to the `./configure` statement. The `make` step failed about 20 minutes into compiling.

Comment: Can you clarify why it is that you think the regular 64-bit build, without any special options, won't do what you want? As I mentioned above it defaults to building a compiler and support libraries that can target both 32- and 64-bit. It doesn't require building cctools since it will happily use your system versions. The only remotely non-standard thing I had to do when trying that approach was to delete the binutils version of `strip` from the install prefix prior to configuring GCC so that the system version would be used.

Comment: It's not that I don't think it will do what I want, it's that it won't. Or building it doesn't work using either the Xcode developer tools (LLVM GCC 4.2) or with MacPorts GCC 4.7.2. The `make` step will leave with a fatal error at some point during the build. In the description I gave above, it takes about an hour of compiling before it quits with a fatal error.

Comment: I'd suggest trying your steps above without the `--target=i386-apple-darwin` option to the two configure scripts. That's precisely what I tried after messing around with `cctools` and `ld64` for a while, and it worked without any of the hassle.  Another hint that may be useful is to build with `make -j $(sysctl -n hw.availcpu)` to ensure that all of your cores will be used, and perhaps even configure GCC with `--enable-languages=c,c++` so that it doesn't spend a ton of time on building Fortran and Java support.

Comment: Without specifying the target, I get 64-bit binaries, e.g.:`$ lipo -info ../third-party/binutils/bin/ar`
`Non-fat file: ../third-party/binutils/bin/ar is architecture: x86_64`

Comment: Targeting 32-bit requires only that the tools support generating 32-bit code, not that they themselves run as 32-bit. Check the output of `ar --help` to see the list of targets that it supports. It'll look something like `supported targets: mach-o-x86-64 mach-o-i386 …`, indicating that it can indeed target i386.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the full steps I used to build GCC 4.7 and confirm that it can generate i386 binaries.

Comment: I was able to compile GCC 4.7.2, but, as I noticed before, the static libraries are 64-bit: `lipo -info ../third-party/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libstdc++.a` `input file ../third-party/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libstdc++.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: ../third-party/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libstdc++.a is architecture: x86_64`

Comment: Try looking at `lib/i386/libstdc++.a` rather than `lib/libstdc++.a`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Okay, I'm going to try a clean build of GCC 4.7.2 from a vanilla setup of 10.8 + Xcode developer tools (LLVM-GCC 4.2). If that compiles, then I'll try building an app using `-m32`, `--static-libgcc` and `--static-libstdc++` flags. If `lipo` and `otool -L` confirm that the resulting binary is `i386` and links to the static GCC C/C++ libraries, then I'll give you the points.

Comment: This worked — thank you. However, I had to make some changes that I'm unsure are correct, or have side-effects I'm unsure of. I will write a follow-up in my question later tonight or tomorrow which explains what changes I had to make, in order to build a static `i386` binary from a mix of C and C++ code.

Comment: This *almost* worked. I can make `i386` static binaries which appear to work properly, but even with the changes needed, `x86_64` static binaries quit with an `Abort trap: 6` error. If I remove the `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` flags, then I get a working 64-bit binary, but that binary unfortunately uses dynamic libraries. So I'm close, but as I can't make both 32- and 64-bit binaries, I'm stuck.

Comment: What program is aborting for you when compiled for x86_64 with a static libgcc / libstdc++? The trivial program that I posted above runs just fine for me when built for either i386 and x86_64.

Comment: It may also be worth asking a new question for this x86_64 issue given that this question was initially about building a compiler that could target i386 only.

Comment: The code for the program I'm compiling is too large to post into this or another question. I had to make some changes to the build process (both to gcc and mostly my binary) just to get a `i386` binary to compile. It takes about two hours to compile `gcc` alone. I'm wondering if I'm tilting at windmills...

Comment: It seems like the static GCC runtime libraries on OS X aren't particularly well-supported. MacPorts and the like don't appear to even try making them work. I'd love to help further but I'm out of suggestions without the ability to debug the problem. I hope you do find some way to make it work!

Comment: I think I'm just going wave my white flag of surrender at Cupertino and bundle dylibs in an installer. Not as elegant as standalone binaries, and more fragile, but you win this one, Apple!

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted since we seem to have wrapped things up. It's worth noting that an installer isn't necessary for bundling dylibs unless you have particularly special requirements. In most cases you can just ship them inside the .app wrapper of your application.

Comment: These are command-line tools. An .app bundle is not a very convenient way to use them because `open` doesn't play too well with command-line arguments.